# How can I declare AuditLog.Read.All as a Delegated permission on my Azure AD V2 app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The [documentation for the Microsoft Graph directoryAudits](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryaudit_list) endpoint requires the AuditLog.Read.All as a required permission. It is listed as available for both Delegated and Application permission types.

However, I cannot add AuditLog.Read.All as a Delegated permission to my V2 registered app, either via apps.dev.microsoft.com (it does not show as an option in the Delegated permissions picker), or via the new Application Registrations endpoint in the Azure Portal (it throws an HTTP 400 error when attempting to save after selecting AuditLog.Read.All as a Delegated permission).

How do I register AuditLog.Read.All on my application as a delegated permission so that admin consent flow can be performed?

Comment: Seems like a bug there, I suppose you could try to modify the application object directly via MS Graph, but I assume that would cause a 400 too.

Comment: @juunas declaring it (via name) at time of API call works for that call, but to modify the manifest I need to know the scope GUID. My goal here is to get admin consent working for this delegated scope, so I need to get it declared in the manifest.

Comment: Yeah, you can find the scope guid from the service principal for MS Graph API in your tenant :)

Comment: @juunas thanks, found the scope ID that way... but editing manifest in the App Registration Portal directly fails with "The Required Resource Access specified in the request is invalid." :( Same error when patching via Graph.

Comment: @WesK. I see the same behavior with an app registered with Azure AD B2C. On a side note though, adding the AuditLog.Read.All delegated permission as well as granting admin consent works fine for an Azure AD (v1) registered application (just in case that's an option for you)

Comment: @RohitSaigal unfortunately switching to v1 is not an option for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Find your registered app in the App registrations (preview) in the Azure portal(this is for the v2 app), and then in the API Permission, you could find `AuditLog.Read.All` in the delegated permission for Microsoft Graph.

[image]

After you add and update permissions, you could get this:

[image]
For this, you will need to log in an admin account to consent to this permission.

After the admin consents to this, you could find:

[image]

Comment: When I add the same scopes as your image (User.Read, AuditLog.Read.All) to an app registration, I get:     HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax. (XHR)PATCH - https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/AADGraph

Comment: Have you parsed your token in https://jwt.io/, and checked whether the AuditLog.Read.All already existed in the `scp`?

Comment: And if you use the app to acquire token, you will also need to grant AuditLog.Read.All permission in the application permission.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that changing signInAudience in the application manifest from *AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount* to *AzureADMultipleOrgs* allows the AuditLog.Read.All to properly register.